# what did you do / have you done; in this context

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

My dad lent me his car but I did something stupid with; I scratched the car (not very much). After I came back home and because I did something bad to his car I was acting very kindly with him. He looked at me with this smile and he knew that this smile meant something bad so he told me "what have you done?" or "what did you do?"

I would use "what have you done" because the action is not unrelevant to present.

Comment: Please indicate what research you've done and why that wasn't able to help. The difference between present perfect and past is covered extensively on this site.

Comment: I think that in BE they will use more "what you have done" whereas in AE they will use "what did you do"

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, either "what have you done" or "what did you do" is acceptable.

However, there are many errors in the paragraph you provided. Here's a corrected version:

My Dad lent me his car, but I did something stupid with it. I scratched the car, although not by very much. When I came home, because I had done something bad to his car, I was acting very nice toward him. He looked at me with this smile on my face and knew that the smile meant something bad had happened, so he asked me, "What have you done?" or "What did you do?"

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Comment: "Not by very much"?

Comment: It's very informal, but very common, at least in American English.